# ASP.NET MVC2 and routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "edit_product",                                // Route name
    "Product/Edit/{productId}",                    // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Edit", 
          productId = UrlParameter.Optional }      // Parameter defaults
);
```

Why does this code works:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", 
    new { controller = "Product", productId = product.ProductId }) %>
```

And this doesn't:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Product", 
    new { productId = product.ProductId }) %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Product", 
    new { productId = product.ProductId } , null) %>
```

You need the null parameter

Actionlink doesnt have (LinkText, Actionname, Controller, Parameters) but does have
  (LinkText, Actionname, Controller, Parameters, htmlAttributes)

Comment: Thank you! I missed the null parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The first is resolving to [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936.aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues
)
```

There is no overload of [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) that takes three strings and an object. The nearest is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) that takes two strings and two objects:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

so I wouldn't expect it to do what you want.